# Maximo/ ESRIIntegrationImpl.js missing?

Tags: javascript, widget, spatial, maximo

I'm trying to add a custom tool to my Maximo Spatial Implementation. I've found that I may need to add the configuration of the tool to ESRIIntegrationImpl.js file.

But I couldn't find the file in my implementation. I'm using Maximo Spatial 7.6.

My doubt is: was the file removed in the version 7.6? Is the process of adding a custom tool to Maximo Spatial changed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.